# Which SMTP relay to replace Mandrill

Tags: civimail, smtp, mandrill, amazon-ses

as mandrill have just announced they are becoming an add-on to mailchimp, and transactional email service will be attached to a subscription to MailChimp.
And as my provider mail service drop all bounces, I have to fall back on other solutions that can be integrated properly with CiviMail.
What are solutions (free or very little expensive because we are a very small structure) that would send 600 messages per month maximum (Google, Zoho, ...)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See also: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/free-mandrill-usage-going-away-what-alternatives-work-well

Answer (score 3):

This conversation has been taking place on the CiviCRM Partners' list in the past week.  Fortunately, some folks from the list created a wiki page to track the best options, which is available here: [Mailing Providers](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Mailing+providers).

I like Amazon SES, which termdark referenced (I'm the author of that documentation they linked).  However, CiviCRM partners with much larger installations don't like it because it lacks some high-end features (e.g. sub-accounting) and because they can vary their throttling.

If you're only sending 600 messages/month, you can probably use your web host's SMTP servers.  If you're on a VPS, you can set up Posfix yourself - you're unlikely to get blacklisted with such a low volume if you configure it right, and being able to configure Postfix is an important part of how to set up Amazon SES.

EDIT: There's a lot of interest amongst the partners in [SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/).  They offer 100,000 free messages a month, and support many of the high-end features.  There's also an extension under development by the folks at [CiviDesk](http://www.cividesk.com) to use the more efficient (and easier to set up) API for bounce handling.

Comment: Thanks for these informations.
In my research, I also found SendinBlue (https://fr.sendinblue.com)

Comment: On another thread this extension was posted recently (I haven't tested it yet): https://github.com/proexchange/com.pesc.sparkpost

Answer (score 2):

Amazon SES is a suitable replacement for those on a budget. There's some useful documentation on getting it set up with CiviCRM at: https://hq.palantetech.coop/projects/commons/wiki/Amazon_SES_for_CiviCRM

I'd advise you to set up the Postix server as SES lacks much of the more useful functionality of Mandrill.