# Transactional emails, such as confirmations, are not going out

Tags: confirmation

I am in the process of setting up CiviCRM to send via SparkPost using the following extension - com.cividesk.email.sparkpost

CiviMail appears to be working (both using test emails and cron) but, confirmations are not being sent when people subscribe to mailing lists or to become members.

**Administer > CiviMail > CiviMail Component Settings:** shows that 'Enable Double Opt-in for Profile Group(s) field' is checked.

Is there something else that needs to be done such as a scheduled job?

Answer (score 2):

CiviMail isn't responsible for anything other than Bulk Mailouts.

There are Scheduled Jobs required for things like Scheduled Reminders which you can find at civicrm/admin/job?reset=1

In case you hadn't spotted, there have been two SparkPost extensions released. the other is [here](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost-civicrm-integration). Not suggesting either is better, or even how relevant it is to your issue

If you just click 'Send Email' via Actions on a civi contact record, does it get sent?

And what is the outcome from send a Test Email from /civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1

Comment: just as a 'note': I see a post here http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9917/free-mandrill-usage-going-away-what-alternatives-work-well/10272?noredirect=1#comment10990_10272 saying Transaction Email bounces now being managed by https://github.com/proexchange/com.pesc.sparkpost